# Filter Blur on triangle

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add an overflow hidden or something similar to the solid triangle so it still shows a blurred area but the edges are solid? I'm using this css as you can see in the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6a26c595/

```
.arrow-up {
    border-left: 350px solid transparent;
    border-right: 350px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 350px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -310px;
    filter: blur(7px);
    left: -351px;
}

.arrow-behind {
    border-left: 300px solid transparent;
    border-right: 300px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 300px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 19px;
    left: 49px;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You want a blurred triangle with solid sides? (Sounds like a contradiction) Could you provide an image of what you are going for?

Comment: I'm just wanting a blurred triangle but rather than having the feathered out edges i want them to be sharp. So i was thinking if there was a way to create a smaller triangle and if it an overflow hidden that would hide the edges of the blurred triangle giving them a sharp look